# Java Set Bigdecimal abbreviation

Tags: java

Does Java have a BigDecimal set abbreviation?

This is for float. What is for BigDecimal?

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

data.setPaymentAmount(25F);
```

Comment: `new BigDecimal("25")` or `BigDecimal.valueOf(12)` - see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for all methods and constructors (it is not a primitive type, nor has it some *abbreviation* {e.g. like primitives or `String`}) - available literals: [JLS 3.10 Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10)

Comment: No.  No it doesn't.

Comment: What you are asking about is a **literal** not an "abbreviation".  (And the answer is still No.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tl;dr

Replace your `float` numeric literal with passing text to a constructor.

```
data.setPaymentAmount( new BigDecimal( "25" ) );
```

## Details

The first word in the [Javadoc for `BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) is [“immutable”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). So you cannot change the number content of such an object. Calling methods such as [`add`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#add(java.math.BigDecimal)), `subtract`, `multiply`, and `divide` result in a new separate `BigDecimal` object being instantiated.

Never use a `float`/`Float` or `double`/`Double` as seen in your code, **not if you care about accuracy**. Those floating point types [trade away accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) for speed of performance. The `BigDecimal` class does the opposite, trading away speed for accuracy.

Your example code uses a `float` literal: `25F`. Passing a `float` to the constructor of `BigDecimal` defeats the purpose of using a `BigDecimal` if your purpose is accuracy.

To maintain accuracy, use `String` inputs.

```
BigDecimal x ;                 // Null object reference. No number involved.
x = new BigDecimal( "25" ) ;   // Representing *exactly* twenty-five in a new object of type `BigDecimal`.
```

In your code, if your `set…` method is meant to install a `BigDecimal` object, pass a `BigDecimal` object.

```
data.setPaymentAmount( new BigDecimal( "25" ) ) ;
```

Comment: *"The BigDecimal class does the opposite, trading away speed for accuracy."* - Caveat: even so you will still be forced to sacrifice accuracy in some cases; e.g. divisions producing a recurring fraction (in base 2).